# Plot mysteriously not working

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm running this code to plot an equation but it simply won't work

```
B = 0.029*Log[r]*Cos[θ][Sin[θ]]^2;

f[x_, y_, z_] = -Grad[Simplify[TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", B, {r, θ,   ϕ} -> {x, y, z}]], {x, y, z}]

VectorPlot3D[f[x, y, z], {x, 10, 20}, {y, 10, 20}, {z, 10, 20}]
```

When I use an equation like

```
 B = -((0.0003*Cos[θ] (Sin[θ])^2)/r^2)
```

The plot works, but it doesn't work with the other equation I want.. why?

Comment: Remove the square brackets from `[Sin[theta]]^2` in your definition of `B`. Square brackets are only used for function calls in MMA, not to alter operation precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MarcoB pointed out above in the comments, there is an extra set of square brackets in `[Sin[θ]]^2` expression. The correct B function should be `B = 0.029 Log[r] Cos[θ] Sin[θ]^2;`

Square brackets in Mathematica are reserved for enclosing arguments of functions. Here is a link to Wolfram's documentation on [howto/UseBracketsAndBracesCorrectly](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/UseBracketsAndBracesCorrectly.html).

More generally though, I often have syntax errors that prevent plots from showing up, because the plot function doesn't evaluate to a numerical expression. Whenever this happens, I evaluate a point in the plot domain to help debug. For example, in this case, evaluating `f[10, 10, 10]`  or `f[10, 10, 10]//N` returns a list with square brackets in the output that points to the problem. Once you remove the extra square brackets, this evaluates to a numerical expression.